# SQL group by listing all values for each name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to get this to not repeat the students name so much. I am pretty new to SQL queries. Just wondering if there's a better way to do this by having all the listed in one row for each student.

```
SELECT s.name students, c.name classes 
FROM students s  INNER JOIN enrollments e ON s.id=e.student_id 
INNER JOIN classes c ON e.class_id=c.id 
GROUP BY s.name, c.name;
```

gives me

```
students  |    classes
-----------+----------------
 Paige     | Calculus
 Pajak     | Calculus
 Pajak     | Yoga
 Pamela    | Calculus
 Pamela    | Cooking Pasta
 Pamela    | Football
 Pamela    | Singing
 Pamela    | Yoga
 Parker    | English
 Parker    | Fruit
 Parker    | Social Studies
```

Just curious if there's a cleaner way.

Comment: Generally you wouldn't use GROUP BY without an AGGREGATE function (SUM, AVG, COUNT, etc.). Sounds like you are trying to get a PIVOT function? Not sure what else you would mean by "listed in one row for each student". You have multiple classes values for each student. Thus, multiple rows per student.

Comment: I think that answers my question. From what you're saying, if I understand correctly, is that since each student has multiple classes then there *will* be multiple rows for each student. I was trying to get all the classes in one row for each student, but it sounds like that isnt posisble. Thank you :D .

Comment: It is, using a number of functions, but not just a basic SELECT. I believe with PosgreSQL you can use [STRING_AGG](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-aggregate.html)

Comment: `string_agg`!!! Thank you sir!!

Comment: @JacobH I had this working the other day. When I went to show a classmate of mine it all of a sudden stopped working. I'm still getting the information that I need but no longer listed on one row as before. I'm going to keep looking for a fix, but do you have any ideas on what might have caused that to stop working as intended?

Comment: Did you add something else to the group by?

Comment: @JacobH That was it. Thank you. Got used to my terminal yelling at me to have the other thing in my `SELECT` in the group by, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big thanks to `@Jacob H`! His suggestion of `string_agg` worked like a charm.

```
SELECT s.name students, string_agg(c.name, '|') classes 
FROM students s  INNER JOIN enrollments e ON s.id=e.student_id 
INNER JOIN classes c ON e.class_id=c.id 
GROUP BY s.name;
```

results in...

```
students  |                   classes
-----------+----------------------------------------------
 Piper     | Social Studies|Fruit
 Paige     | Calculus
 Pedro     | Programming
 Peter     | Yoga|Gym
 Peggy     | Fruit
 Patricia  | Social Studies
 Paula     | Fruit|Football
 Phoebe    | English|Gym|Cooking Pasta
 Pamela    | Cooking Pasta|Yoga|Football|Calculus|Singing
 Parker    | Social Studies|English|Fruit
 Priscilla | How to Guitar|Gym
 Priyal    | Programming
 Patrick   | Cooking Pasta|Singing|How to Guitar
 Puja      | Singing|Programming|English|Social Studies
 Paxton    | Gym
 Pepe      | Yoga
 Penelope  | Cooking Pasta
 Pajak     | Yoga|Calculus
 Parth     | How to Guitar
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you want `listagg()`:

```
SELECT s.name as students, listagg(c.name) within group(order by c.name) as classes 
FROM students s INNER JOIN
     enrollments e
     ON s.id = e.student_id INNER JOIN
     classes c
     ON e.class_id = c.id 
GROUP BY s.name, c.name;
```

This creates a comma delimited list of the classes each student is in.

EDIT:

In Postgres, you can use `string_agg()`:

```
SELECT s.name as students, string_agg(c.name order by c.name) as classes 
FROM students s INNER JOIN
     enrollments e
     ON s.id = e.student_id INNER JOIN
     classes c
     ON e.class_id = c.id 
GROUP BY s.name, c.name;
```

Comment: It looks like DB2 syntax. This is tagged Postgresql

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto . . . Actually, Oracle.  I thought the original question was tagged plsql, but the tag was actually psql.